# Linear programming for prefix of graph

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming

Question: Consider an arbitrary directed graph $G$ with weighted vertices, the weights can be positive, negative or $0$. The prefix of $G$ is a subset of vertices $P$ such that there's no edge $(u \rightarrow v)$ if $v \in P$ and $u \not\in P$. Find an integer linear programming to describe the maximum weight prefix of G.

I'm new to linear programming and struggling in come up a LP solution.

The objective function seems trivial, we let $x_v$ be a variable to indicate whether that vertex in or not in the prefix. Thus we have, $$\sum_{v \in V} w(v)x_v$$

However, I'm not sure how to impose the prefix constraint such that if we pick a vertex $v$, we must have to pick its prefix vertex say $u$, if there's a directed edge from $u$ to $v$. So it seems like we have to check all edges, for each directed edge $(u \rightarrow v)$, if $v \in P$ then $u  \in P$. I can only describe this verbally, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you are looking for an **integer** linear program.

Comment: That's right, sorry I forgot to mention this.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to correct the problem statement based on the feedback you have received.  Don't just append "Edit: some more stuff".  Instead, revise it so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To encode the fact that if $(u,v)$ is an edge then you you cannot have $u \not\in P$ and $v \in P$ you can add (for each edge) the following constraint:

$$
(1-x_u) + x_v \le 1,
$$

equivalently:
$$
x_v - x_u \le 0.
$$